# sharpie bind command gives error 'Foundation/Foundation.h' file not found

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, objective-sharpie

I'm trying to create a binding library for the GoogleMLKit/TextRecognition. For that first I created a Xcode project and installed the pods and tried to run `sharpie bind` command to generate `ApiDefinitions.cs` and `Structs.cs`.
This is the command I used `sharpie bind -sdk iphoneos -output ./ -namespace Xam.TextRecognition.iOS -scope ./MLKitTextRecognition.framework/Headers ./MLKitTextRecognition.framework/Headers/*.h`.
I get the following error on terminal

```
fatal error: 'Foundation/Foundation.h' file not found
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Any Updates @WarKirin ? Are you able to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue with the `sharpie bind` command.

Provide the missing header files like this :

```
sharpie bind {pathToFramework}/Headers/Test.h -scope {pathToFramework}/Headers -c -F
```

The folder `{pathToFramework}/Headers` (in your case `./MLKitTextRecognition.framework/Headers`) is the folder where you will put the header files missing, for example `Foundation.h`.

Find the file on your computer then paste it there.

Replace `pathToFramework` with your framework local path.